# How to create a fast-then-gradually-slowing interval?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a interval where a color will flash fast, then gradually slow down to a full stop. My code right now is a big jumble of something I now don't understand.

My code is actually just trying to set a timeout with a varying time. I tried a small demo which printed a letter, than set a timeout to run it's self again, but it incremented a timeout each time, creating an exponential letter curve; but it did't stop.

https://jsfiddle.net/eslota52/a6jg1Loh/
(the code is too long)
try looking at the `addTimeout();` function, and the end of the `doThat();` function, for some help.

---

```js
var colord = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var colorCode_1;
var colorCode_2;
var colorCode_3;
var colorCode_4;
var colorCode_5;
var colorCode_6;
var finalColor;
var finalColorHex;
var timex;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(doThat, 100);

function doThat() {
  timex = timex + 50;
  colorCode_1 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  colorCode_2 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  colorCode_3 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  colorCode_4 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  colorCode_5 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  colorCode_6 = colord[Math.trunc(Math.random() * colord.length)];
  finalColor = colorCode_1 + colorCode_2 + colorCode_3 + colorCode_4 + colorCode_5 + colorCode_6;
  finalColorHex = '#' + finalColor;
  document.getElementById('h1element').innerHTML = finalColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = finalColorHex;
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    addTimeout();
  }, 2500);
}

function addTimeout() {
  if (timex <= 1000) {
    timex = timex + 100;
    both();
  } else if (timex <= 2500) {
    timex = timex + 250;
    both();
  } else if (timex <= 5000) {
    both();
  }
}

function both() {
  addTimeout();
  doThat();
}
doThat();
```

```html
<center><h1 id="h1element">

</h1></center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Function that gives you a random number
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// Generates an hexadecimal color like "#45FF04"
function generateColor() {
  const arr = [
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
  ];

  let color = '#';

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    color = `${color}${arr[getRandomInt(arr.length - 1)]}`;
  }

  return color;
}

// Change i to go slower
const i = 10;

let timeToWaitForAChange = 50;

// Change increasingSpeed to makes more time to display all colors
let increasingSpeed = 100;
let nbColorChange = 0;

// How many colors you want to display ?
const maxNbColorChange = 50;


// Ex: If you want all 50 colors to be played very fast, use :
// i = 1
// inscreasingSpeed = 1

// Perform a color change and trigger the next one using setTimeout
function changeTheColor() {
  // Get the new color to apply
  const color = generateColor();

  // Apply the color
  document.getElementById('h1element').innerHTML = color;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

  // Decide the next delay to change the color
  timeToWaitForAChange += increasingSpeed;

  nbColorChange += 1;

  increasingSpeed = (nbColorChange * i);

  if (nbColorChange >= maxNbColorChange) {
    // It was the last stop
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(() => changeTheColor(), timeToWaitForAChange);
}

changeTheColor();
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 id="h1element">

  </h1>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but I would like it to be a little faster in the beginning and stop quicker. I'm very sorry, but I don't understand how to do that as I am a novice to what you coded.

Comment: What about now ?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I'm sorry if that was a little too much of a burden on you.

Comment: Not a burden, we all are here to help people out during our program compilation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```js
const colord = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

let refreshRateIncrease = 50;
let initialRefreshRate  = 0;
const maxMili             = 2000; //2 seconds

function randomNumber(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function fastToSlow(refreshRate){
  setTimeout(function(){

    let color = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      color += colord[randomNumber(colord.length)];
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = color;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + color;

    //make it slower...
    refreshRate += refreshRateIncrease;
    //increase the refreshRateIncrease so it becomes slower much more quicklier
    refreshRateIncrease += 0.2 * refreshRateIncrease;
    //if the time passes a certain point, quit.
    if(refreshRate >= maxMili){
      return;
    }
    
    //call fast to slow again with the new refreshRate
    fastToSlow(refreshRate);
  }, refreshRate);
}

fastToSlow(initialRefreshRate);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called an "Easing Function", you can learn about them [here](https://easings.net/).

What you exactly need is an "Ease Out" function, I selected for you the "Ease Out Circular" function, you can try any other with similar characteristics. In the code below you can configure the amount of updates and the duration of the updates to achieve the desired effect, I selected 100 updates during 5 seconds.

```js
const { floor, random, sqrt } = Math;
const { now } = Date;

const randomColor = () => `#${Array.from(Array(3), () => floor(random() * 255).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')}`;

const element = document.getElementById('h1element');
const bodyStyle = document.body.style;

const duration = 5000;

const start = now();

const totalUpdates = 100;

let elapsed = 0;
let updates = 0;

const easeOutCirc = (t, b, c, d) => {

    t /= d;
    t--;

    return c * sqrt(1 - t*t) + b;
}

const changeColor = () => {

    const color = randomColor();
    
    elapsed = now() - start;
    
    const newUpdates = floor(easeOutCirc(elapsed, 0, totalUpdates, duration));
    
    if (newUpdates > updates) {
        updates = newUpdates;
        
        bodyStyle.background = color;
        element.innerHTML = color;
    }
    
    if (updates < totalUpdates) {
        requestAnimationFrame(changeColor);
    }
};

changeColor();
```

```html
<center><h1 id="h1element"></h1></center>
```